# Problems with RFacebook on R

Tags: r, facebook, rfacebook

I'm trying to get information about my Facebook user through R (as a scrapping test) and I can't get any result because it only returns my name.

The code I am using is this:

```
token<- '12345' (using fake numbers for this)
me<- getUsers("me", 
              token,
              private_info = T)
me
id         name username first_name middle_name last_name gender locale likes picture birthday
1 24539089155705603 Fake Name Fake LastName       NA         NA          NA        NA     NA     NA    NA      NA       NA
  location hometown relationship_status
1       NA       NA                  NA
```

Why do the other fields return NULL?
I get the token in this page

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: The package [was abandoned 4 years ago](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook) due to change to the Facebook API. You should probably find a different way to get the data you are after.